# Validating list of variables in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XDv0DyD8qxbVhlpDKQLX?p=preview) I have an `ng-repeat` of input fields. Each field has to pass two validations: (1) the value cannot be empty, and (2) if `num = 1` then the value needs to be a number. I'm using `ng-form` in each row to validate the values independently (I cannot have the `ng-repeat` inside a `<form>`.

The problem is that messages are not displayed correctly. To replicate, [in the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XDv0DyD8qxbVhlpDKQLX?p=preview) add a `1` to the third field. It becomes `b1` that is not a valid number, still the `Value should be a number` error message is not displayed. It is displayed after you change the value again, for example to `b11`. Where is the problem and how to fix it?

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="v in vals">
  <ng-form name="formval">
      <input type="text" name="val" ng-model="v.val" style="float:left" 
            ng-change="seeError(formval,v.num,v.val)" required/>
      <div ng-show="!formval.val.$valid" ng-messages="formval.val.$error" class="errorMsg">
           <div ng-message="shouldBeNumber">Value should be a number</div>
           <div ng-message="required">Value cannot be empty</div>
      </div> 
      {{ 'error row #' + $index}} {{formval.val.$error}}
      <br/><br/><br/>
    </ng-form>
 </div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.vals = [
      {val: 'a', num: 0},
      {val: 2, num: 1 },
      {val: 'b', num: 1}
    ];


    $scope.seeError = function(form,num,value){
          delete form.val.$error.shouldBeNumber;
          if (value && value.trim()==="") // omit as form will show an error
              return;
          if (num===1) // should be a number
              if (isNaN(parseFloat(value)))
                  form.val.$error.shouldBeNumber = true;
    };

});
```

Comment: I wonder if you have to use 'ng-form'. How about consider to use 'form'. And why are you using 'text' instead of 'number'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed a little of your code.

Please check this fiddle.

[form validation](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/q69hydva/)

```
$scope.seeError = function(form,num,value){
    form.val.$error.required = false;
    form.val.$error.shouldBeNumber = false;
    if (value===undefined) // omit as form will show an error
        form.val.$error.required = true;
    if (num===1&&isNaN(Number(value))) // should be a number
        form.val.$error.shouldBeNumber = true;
};
```

I am not certain that my fiddle is proper to your purpose,

but I hope this can help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should fix some bugs at first:

1) add this to the **head**-tag

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.js"></script>
```

2) and in the JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);
```

then...

in html

```
<input type="text" name="val" ng-model="v.val" style="float:left" required ng-model-sniffer/>
<div ng-messages="formval.val.$error" class="errorMsg">
    <div ng-message="shouldBeNumber">Value should be a number</div>
    <div ng-message="required">Value cannot be empty</div>
</div>
```

in JS

```
app.directive('ngModelSniffer', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, model)
        {
            model.$validators.shouldBeNumber = function(modelValue, viewValue)
            {
                return !isNaN(parseFloat(viewValue));
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I prefer not to add a dependency

Answer (score 1):

when the list is initially displayed ng-change is not fired because

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input
>   value causes a new value to be committed to the model.
>
> It will not be evaluated:
>
> - if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has not changed
> - if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay null
> - if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value

you can use a custom filter to achieve the same behaviour

html

```
<div ng-repeat="v in vals | filter:checkError">
</div>
```

js

```
$scope.checkError = function (item) {

    if(item.val is not number)
        displayError = true;

    return true;
};
```

Comment: In the question plunk, add a `1` to the third field. It becomes `b1` that is not a valid number, still the message is not displayed. It is displayed after you change the value again. Why is that? Is it a $digest problem?